# Vue.js production build has different generated CSS style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, webpack, sass

After building my project for production (`build`) certain elements have a different style (not present when using `serve`)

Details:

I'm using both CoreUI Pro 3 (Vue 2) and BootstrapVue 2.21.2 which both use bootstrap 4 (but customized).

The problem is form inputs' valid or invalid state icon is misaligned in production but fine in development. So `.form-control` with `.is-valid` for example have the wrong `background-position`.

In development two styles are generated that are equivalent (top one is being used).

```css
html:not([dir="rtl"]) .was-validated .form-control:valid, html:not([dir="rtl"]) .form-control.is-valid {
    background-position: center right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem);
}
.was-validated .form-control:invalid, .was-validated .form-control:valid, .form-control.is-invalid, .form-control.is-valid {
    background-position: right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem) center;
}
```

In production two styles are also generated with the top one being used - which is the issue. Forcing it to use the second one fixes it.

```css
html:not([dir=rtl]) .form-control.is-valid, html:not([dir=rtl]) .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    background-position: 100% calc(.375em + .1875rem);
}
.form-control.is-invalid, .form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:invalid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    background-position: right calc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
}
```

So is there a **nice** way of making it use the correct style or figuring out the root of the issue?
*There are several hacky ways but I'm not sure which one to purse first.*

I have tried updating all the various sass loaders and webpack but nothing has changed.
I also tried duplicating the import files for Core UI and modifying the order of import of the form mixin but that didn't help (I'm also not a sass expert). And moving `@mixin form-validation-state($state, $color, $icon)` around didn't seem to help.

The specific import order in my `styles.scss` (the opposite order doesn't work):

```
@import "~@coreui/coreui-pro/scss/coreui";
@import '~bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

I know there could be a lot of relevant files but these should be a good start. Can provide more details if needed.